# Sending message to a remote user using msg

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I send a message from one user to another user using the `msg` command if both accounts are on same server and are using a client machine?

I know the basic use of `msg` command:

```
msg "username" "message you want to send"
```

What parameters should I pass here so that other user can get my message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MS doc on the syntax is here.](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_msg.mspx?mfr=true)

Your syntax looks fine, but you may need to enter the server or session name.

The `msg` command uses the domain to contact the user, so as long as they are on your domain with domain credentials it will send to whatever PC they are on.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, I tried msg [username] /server:[servername] /w [message], but I think we do not have sufficient rights.

Comment: @searock - it's possible.  Sometimes it is disabled since spyware/adware use it to spoof system messages.

Comment: Well then I guess our Admin must has disabled it. Anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: How about using SysInternals psexec?

Answer (score 1):

```
msg /SERVER:<server_name> * /TIME:<time_in_seconds_to display> "<message_text>"
```

Just edit the text. Dont delete `"`, `*` or `/`. Write them as they are.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

msg Username Server:Servername  ( Then Press Enter )

Type your message then press Enter again

Then Press CTRL +Z And Enter

Think that should work